# Alternative Suggestions for MultiThreading

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am making use of multithreading ExecutorService Interface to execute the tasks parallely. But there is a shared resource here and i need to make it in synchronize block so that only one thread can access it at a time. As i made it in synchronize block, the job is taking about more than 3hours to complete. I dont see any point of using Multithreading here because of the synchronized block. Can any one suggest is there any alternative or the best way of implementing the below example to run the loop parallely faster please:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
for(String str : arrayList){
   for(String str1 : arrayList1){
     for(String str2 : arrayList2){
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //do Something
                            synchornize block{}
                        }
        });
     }
   }
}
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: I dont know who gave a negative to this question, but please can you let me know the reason? so that i will not repeat it here?

Comment: Not me, but I think the answer all depends on what code is inside your executor block.  And out of curiosity, how long does it take with a single thread?

Comment: So basically we will be doing API calls inside the nested for loop. So you mean to ask if i run this with a single thread instead of 100 threads ? It takes for ever i believe i have never tested that..but if its 100 threads its taking about 3hours..Actually it might takes 3hours even with single thread as there is a synchronized block for most part of it. @SteveSmith

Comment: If that's the case, then I would post another question along the lines of "how can I reduce the synchronization required on this code", and post your `synchornize block` [sic] code.  As it is, multi threading isn't making any difference.

Comment: You are in need for a solid architecture for your problem, but don't specify anything about your problem. We cannot help you with such little information.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to redesign your code to either avoid completely or minimize the synchronized block. For example, you could place the results of the API calls on a synchronized queue and have another thread process them.